# Why does gradient descent update 0-valued weights at all?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, theory, gradient-descent

I was reading [this question](https://www.quora.com/If-one-initializes-a-set-of-weights-in-a-Neural-Network-to-zero-is-it-true-that-in-future-iterations-they-will-not-be-updated-by-gradient-descent-and-backpropagation) and the discussion makes sense to me: when all weights are initialized to zero, gradient descent can't tell where the error came from, so it can't update those weights.

What I don't understand is why I can't see this empirically. I'm running the following piece of code ([runnable here](https://github.com/iRapha/tensorflow-play/blob/master/update.py)):

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2,1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 2])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1])

pred = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, w) + b)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred - y))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    for i in range(100):
        for x_ex, y_ex in dataset:
            sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: x_ex, y: y_ex})
            print(sess.run(w))
```

And the output I'm seeing is like:

```
[[ 0.]
 [ 0.]]
[[ 0.02530853]
 [ 0.        ]]
[[ 0.02530853]
 [ 0.02499614]]
[[-0.00059909]
 [-0.00091148]]
[[-0.00059909]
 [-0.00091148]]
[[ 0.02472398]
 [-0.00091148]]
[[ 0.02472398]
 [ 0.02410331]]
```

If the weights start out as zero, why is gradient descent able to update them at all?

As a follow up question, if a weight is randomnly initialized to be positive, but the optimal value for that weight is negative, do we just have to trust that in an update step the optimizer won't accidentally update the weight to be 0 (and thus halt the weight's updatability)? I know the odds of weight + update step being exactly 0 are almost neglibible, but it could still be an issue, especially with millions of weights in a NN.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily a problem in gradient descent, but how the partial derivatives are being calculated with backpropagation.

> How bp computes the partial derivative for weights in layer l:
>   `δ/δΘ^{l}_{ij}=a^l_jδ^{l+1}_i` where activation 'a' is applying the non-linear
>   function g (e.g. sigmoid, tanh, ReLU) to the neuron's output:
>   `a^l_j=g(Θ^{l−1}a^{l−1})` and where delta is the difference propagated backwards
>   from the successive layer: `δ^l=(Θ^l)^Tδ^{l+1}.∗g′(Θ^{l−1}a^{l−1})`
>
> The .* stands for element-wise multiplication.
>
> So if you looked at how the activation is computed, zero-weights
>   prevent the activation from increasing or decreasing. All-zero weights
>   mean zero activation.

There are other ways to calculate the gradient which do not have this issue!